# Microsoft Excel data rearrange - split column data in half

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

Is there any way to rearrange data in Excel like in the image below? I also want to remove duplicate rows and keep unique values.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The answer to your question is "maybe". It depends critically upon the relationship between the "ACTION_DATE" and "NOTES" rows of your input table. Is first "ACTION_DATE"  row always associated with first "NOTE" row, second with second, etc.

Comment: Are you asking how to basically split data in half, then take the bottom half and align it to the top half? Then after that, remove duplicate entries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Total number of rows in data less header

```
=COUNTA($A:$A)-1
```

Formula in D2

```
=B2
```

Formula in E2 (first cell halfway down B)

```
=INDEX($B:$B, INT((COUNTA($A:$A)-1)/2)+ROW())
```

Now copy the formula down until row #(COUNTA($A:$A)-1)/2+1

To filter unique values, see [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-ccf664b0-81d6-449b-bbe1-8daaec1e83c2) or in Excel 365 use the UNIQUE function in a formula to generate a new table of data.